# Exporting XLSX worksheets (multiple) as seperate CSV Sheets with nested if statements

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am trying to export 15 worksheets from an excel workbook to CSV files. The workbook contains 18 sheets in total. The first three sheets do not need to be exported as they contain raw data, instructions and calculations.

The CSV files produced are for import into Microsoft Dynamics AX. I need to clear any cel containing "~" prior to saving as csv. But only from the 15 sheets for export.

I found multiple threads on this forum that allow me to create a csv succesfully.

My VBA ended up looking like this: (hack together of a few code sets)

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String
Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
Dim CurrentFormat As Long
CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
' Store current details for the workbook
SaveToDirectory = "C:\Temp\Prices\CSV\"
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If WS.Name <> "Instructions" And WS.Name <> "Parameters" And WS.Name <> "BI Data & Worksheet" Then

    Sheets(WS.Name).Copy
    For Each Cell In [b:b]
    If Cell.Value = "~" Then Cell.ClearContents
    'put any value you want here
    Next Cell
    Sheets(WS.Name).Copy
    For Each Cell In [A:A]
    If Cell.Value = "~" Then Cell.ClearContents
    'put any value you want here
    Next Cell


    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
' Temporarily turn alerts off to prevent the user being prompted
'  about overwriting the original file.
End Sub
```

Where I am running into an issue is that while the export runs fine, and the CSV's look great, all the temporary "copy" workbooks are no longer closed by `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False` statement.

I am sure this has to do with my nested IF statements but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually close them after you are done.

```
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Loop though each workbook
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks

        'Activate the workbook
        wb.Activate
        if wb.name = "something you want to close" then
            wb.Close
        end if

    Next wb

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

**EDIT:** More info on the original issue. See comments

```
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If WS.Name <> "Instructions" And WS.Name <> "Parameters" And WS.Name <> "BI Data & Worksheet" Then

    'By doing this copy, Excel is opening an additional workbook.
    'Let's call it "Book1"
    'Book1 is now active
    Sheets(WS.Name).Copy
    For Each Cell In [b:b]
    If Cell.Value = "~" Then Cell.ClearContents
        'put any value you want here
    Next Cell

    'By doing this copy, Excel is opening an additional workbook.
    'Let's call it "Book2".
    'Book2 is now active. Book1 is no longer active.
    Sheets(WS.Name).Copy
    For Each Cell In [A:A]
    If Cell.Value = "~" Then Cell.ClearContents
         'put any value you want here
    Next Cell

    'This is working on the active workbook "Book2"
    'Book1 is no longer active so it will not get saved or closed.
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
End If
Next
```

If you were only doing the copy once, I think it would work the way you want.

If you want to copy the sheet into the same workbook, you have to use the After:=Sheets("SheetName") argument.  Then you will not have to worry about closing the books.

```
Sheets(WS.name).Copy After:=Sheets("SomeSheetName") 
ActiveSheet.Name = "SomeNewSheetName"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Mathew, thankyou for the quick response. This certainly works. I would stil be interested in what I am doing wrong with my nested if statement.

Comment: @Niels de Milliano Only one workbook can be active at a time.By doing the Sheets(WS.name).Copy you are opening additional workbooks, leaving the last one to not be active. I'll add to my answer to elaborate.  Give me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

thanks! spot on!

I removed the second ws sheets copy and everything works as expected:

```
Sheets(ws.Name).Copy
For Each Cell In [b:b]
If Cell.Value = "~" Then Cell.ClearContents
'put any value you want here
Next Cell
For Each Cell In [A:A]
If Cell.Value = "~" Then Cell.ClearContents
'put any value you want here
Next Cell
```

On a side note: the sheets I export to CSV have formulas (nested if statements) coppied down to row 100,000. If certain parameters are met then the cells are filled with a lookup of another cel on another worksheet.

Initially if the parameters were not met then I was displaying "" or nothing. When exporting to CSV however these cells were filled with a comma. I think because there was a formula there.

By displaying "~" as a result of the formula I can clear the cells entirely prior to export, using the above VBA.

The comma in a csv export for a cel containing a fomula but no contents is a problem many people encounter judging by the number of forum posts on this matter. I hope this trick helps someone.